# How to pass Date range parameter from C# to a ValueRange crystals report

Tags: c#, parameters, crystal-reports

I have difficulty to pass a Date Range from C# to Crystal Report.

- Here i have two value from my C# form `StartDate` & `EndDate`.
- And i have a Parameter field name `Date` with **Allow Range Value** in Crystal Report.

I try to make a `string []` to pass two value to the crystal report and it prompt error ValueRangeKind.

```
                    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
                    rpt.PrintOptions.PrinterName = pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;

                    rpt.SetParameterValue("Company", nm);
                    rpt.SetParameterValue("Location", cbxloc.ToString().Trim().ToUpper());
                    rpt.SetParameterValue("Product Project", cbxppj.ToString().Trim().ToUpper());
                    rpt.SetParameterValue("Commodity", cbxcommodity.ToString().Trim().ToUpper());

                    rpt.SetParameterValue("Date", new string[]{StartDate,EndDate});
```

This is the error message :

> ParameterFieldException was unhandled:
>   The parameter field current values cannot
>   contain discrete values because the ValueRangeKind property is set to
>   range.

Hope you can understand my situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C#

```
ParameterRangeValue myParameterRangeValue = new ParameterRangeValue();

myParameterRangeValue.StartValue = StartDate;
myParameterRangeValue.EndValue = EndDate;

crReport.SetParameterValue("Date", myParameterRangeValue);
```

VB

```
    Dim myParameterRangeValue As New ParameterRangeValue

    myParameterRangeValue.StartValue = StartDate
    myParameterRangeValue.EndValue = EndDate

    crReport.SetParameterValue("Date", myParameterRangeValue)
```

You need to create a ParameterRangeValue object, fill it in, and pass it to the setter.
You need to pass the dates as strings (I haven't tried with DateTime objects but I don't think it will work), so make sure you convert your DateTime objects to String first.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, I just do not do this.

I find it much better to pass two dates rather than a range, and then use `>=` &  `<=` in crystal.